# Empty getAddToCompareUrl only in guest mode

Tags: magento-1.9, product, compare, variables, methods

I have this variable `$_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)` to get compare url but this is empty in guest mode, only when i signed in magento it's not empty.

I recently migrate from domain and before migrate all working fine but after migrate i have this problem. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I fix this re-enable logs in System>Configuration>Advanced>system